# I can't login to ubuntu 19.04, I can only login as wayland

Tags: login, 19.04, gdm, wayland

When I access my computer the screen goes black and returns to the login screen.

Already tried `/etc/init.d/gdm3` restart and nothing.

logs:

[Xorg.0.log](https://pastebin.com/PSApf9ex)

[Xorg.1.log](https://pastebin.com/EMK0XAGg)

Comment: are you able to login via something like `tty2`? if so, it would be beneficial to log in and post the X logs here

Comment: logs:

https://pastebin.com/PSApf9ex
https://pastebin.com/EMK0XAGg